# Properties file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, properties

I have an application that uses a properties file that was added by hand at the /project/bin folder (Eclipse project). The application locates the file using:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties")
```

Now I want to add this file in Eclipse, so it's actually part of the project. In which directory should I create the file and how can I make sure the application will find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the .properties file anywhere under a project source directory (`src` by default) to make it wind up in the build directory (`bin` by default) as a "resource", when the project is built. Since the `bin` directory is generated, you can't modify its contents by hand, in the way you describe.

There's no need to call `getClassLoader()`; just `getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo")` is fine.